# Working with the Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
theme =  {
           'ADV': ['RAF', 'WS', 'BJ']
           'BC': ['B', 'SS', 'S']
           'LS': ['WF', 'SS'] }

names = ['Dubai', 'India', 'Monacco']

all_themes = {
                'Dubai': {'RAF', 'B'}
                'India': {'WF', 'SS'}
              }
```

Output:

```
{
  'Dubai': ['ADV', 'BC']
  'India': ['IS', 'BC']
  'Monacco': []
 }
```

Iterate through the list **names**, Check the **all_themes** key(city) one by one, if any one of the value is present in **themes** key values, assign the city to the respective key from the **themes**.
For reference, check the output.

Comment: Typo in output `India: ['IS', 'BC']` should be `India: ['LS', 'BC']`. Did you write any code for your task?

Comment: Please also show your attempts. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried to attempt, it's just I didn't insert it into the question. Next time I will make sure I will show my output also. Thank you @rory-daulton

Comment: actually, I am playing with the dictionaries and lists., from next time onwards I will put my efforts also, I have written the same code but in a very lengthy way, wanted a different approach..@ev-kounis

Answer (score 1):

After sanitizing your input:

```
theme =  {'ADV': ['RAF', 'WS', 'BJ'],
          'BC': ['B', 'SS', 'S'],
          'LS': ['WF', 'SS']}

names = ['Dubai', 'India', 'Monacco']

all_themes = {'Dubai': {'RAF', 'B'},
              'India': {'WF', 'SS'}}
```

you can write a handy dictionary comprehension like this:

```
res = {k: [k_ for k_, v_ in theme.items() if any(x in v_ for x in all_themes.get(k, []))] for k in names}
```

which produces:

```
{'Dubai': ['ADV', 'BC'], 'India': ['BC', 'LS'], 'Monacco': []}
```

---

The comprehension details:

```
{k: <value> for k in names}
```

so far so good, but what should `<value>` be?..

> *Check the `all_themes` key(city) one by one, if any one of the value is present in `theme`'s key values, assign the city to the respective key from the `theme`'s.*

aka:

*a list of `theme` keys for which at least one value they contain can be found in the corresponding `all_themes` values*. So:

```
[k_ for k_, v_ in theme.items() if any(x in sub_v for x in all_themes.get(k, []))]
```